# Using Managed Identities for containers running in PCF to access Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-managed-identity

I would like to know if it is possible to access a blob storage by a container running in Pivotal Cloud Foundry in Azure using a Managed Identity , say system assigned managed identity, or i need to use a Service Principal Object. Any help is appreciated.
Earlier we were using SAS by coding the URL in the code, but want to use Azure AD to do authentication of our API app running inside container. So what is the best way to achieve this

Comment: What's your programming language?

Comment: It is Java. The App is going to fetch data from Azure Blob Storage by querying the metadata in blob storage. The app will be hosted in the containers running in the PCF platform in Azure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Pivotal Cloud Foundry, you could not use the managed identity(MSI) to auth, when using MSI to auth, it essentially makes an API call to azure instance metadata endpoint to get the access token, then use the token to auth,  it is just available in an [Azure environment support MSI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/services-support-managed-identities).

In this case, the best practice is to use a service principal to auth as you mentioned, please follow the steps below.

1.[Register an application with Azure AD and create a service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#register-an-application-with-azure-ad-and-create-a-service-principal).

2.[Get values for signing in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#get-tenant-and-app-id-values-for-signing-in) and [create a new application secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#option-2-create-a-new-application-secret).

3.Navigate to the storage account in the portal -> `Access Control (IAM)` -> assign a [`Storage Blob Data Contributor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#storage-blob-data-contributor)/[`Storage Blob Data Owner`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#storage-blob-data-owner) role to the service principal like below.

[image]

4.The use the java code below, to do a quick test, in my sample, I list all the blobs in a container, just do other things depends on your requirement, replace the values with yours got from step 2.

**`pom.xml`**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
    <version>12.11.0-beta.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**Code**:

```
import com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredential;
import com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredentialBuilder;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobContainerClient;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClient;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClientBuilder;
import com.azure.storage.blob.models.BlobItem;

public  class vacate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String clientId="xxxxxx";
        String clientSecret="xxxxxx";
        String tenantId="xxxxxx";

        ClientSecretCredential credential1 = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
                .tenantId(tenantId)
                .clientId(clientId)
                .clientSecret(clientSecret)
                .build();

        BlobServiceClient storageClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
                .endpoint("https://joystoragev2.blob.core.windows.net")
                .credential(credential1)
                .buildClient();

        BlobContainerClient containerClient = storageClient.getBlobContainerClient("tescon1");
        System.out.println("\nListing blobs...");

        for (BlobItem blobItem : containerClient.listBlobs()) {
            System.out.println("\t" + blobItem.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

For more details, see [Quickstart: Manage blobs with Java v12 SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-java?tabs=powershell).

**Update:**

If you want a user-interactive way to auth, just use these ways - [Authenticating Users](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/master/sdk/identity/azure-identity/README.md#authenticating-users) instead of `ClientSecretCredential`.

[image]

Actually different auth ways in SDK use different auth flows in Azure AD, e.g. `ClientSecretCredential` uses [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow), it is a non-interactive way, `DeviceCodeCredential` uses [device code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-device-code), it is user-interactive way.

To use these user-interactive ways in your case, you need to navigate to the AD App in the portal -> add the delegated permission `user_impersonation` of `Azure storage`.

[image]

[image]

> suppose a particular user should have only read access to the Blob Endpoint and another user might have full CRUD access to the Blob Endpoint, how this will be determined when the user calls this API from a front end application?

Yes, this can be achieved by the [delegated permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#permission-types) added above. When the user use the auth ways to login the AD App, the App will let the user consent the `user_impersonation` permission, after consent(the AAD tenant of the user needs to allow the users to consent the permission by theirselves), the AD App will get the permission from the user, then act on behalf of the user. In short, the permission of the app comes from the user, different users have different permissions, then app will have different permissions.

So in your case, just add users with different roles in the storage account like step 3 above. For read access, just add [`Storage Blob Data Reader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#storage-blob-data-reader), for CURD access, add [`Storage Blob Data Contributor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#storage-blob-data-contributor)/[`Storage Blob Data Owner`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#storage-blob-data-owner), then use the user-interactive ways above, it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I am confused about another thing here. The above what you have explained is getting the SP for the App by registering the app in Azure AD and using that to get access to the Blob Endpoint depending on what kind of role you assign to the App SP to the Blob Storage. My next question is, suppose i have a user who is calling this particular API from a front end application, how am i going to provide the kind of Authorization that the user needs to the Blob Storage , where i am going to set the user authorization or how the user authorization is check

Comment: To add above, suppose a particular user should have only read access to the Blob Endpoint and another user might have full CRUD access to the Blob Endpoint, how this will be determined when the user calls this API from a front end application?